# Why does boost::variant not provide operator !=

Tags: c++, boost-variant

Given two identical `boost::variant` instances **`a`** and **`b`**, the expression **`( a == b )`** is permitted.

However **`( a != b )`** seems to be undefined.  Why is this?

Comment: In my sense its because `==` is needed for `map` contenance, (as well as `hash_value`) but operator != is luxury :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's just not added to the library.  The Boost.Operators won't really help, because either variant would have been derived from boost::operator::equality_comparable.  David Pierre is right to say you can use that, but your response is correct too, that the new operator!= won't be found by ADL, so you'll need a using operator.

I'd ask this on the boost-users mailing list.

**Edit from  @AFoglia's comment:**

Seven months later, and I'm studying Boost.Variant, and I stumble over this better explanation of the omission lists.

http://boost.org/Archives/boost/2006/06/105895.php

`operator==` calls `operator==` for the actual class currently in the variant. Likewise calling `operator!=` should also call `operator!=` of the class. (Because, theoretically, a class can be defined so `a!=b` is not the same as `!(a==b)`.) So that would add another requirement that the classes in the variant have an `operator!=`. (There is a debate over whether you can make this assumption in the mailing list thread.)

Comment: Seven months later, and I'm studying Boost.Variant, and I stumble over this better explanation of the omission http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2006/06/105895.php .  Operator== calls operator== for the actual class currently in the variant.  Likewise calling operator!= should also call operator!= of the class.  (Because, theoretically, a class can be defined so a!=b is not the same as !(a==b).)  So that would add another requirement that the classes in the variant have an operator!=.  (There is a debate over whether you can make this assumption in the mailing list thread.)

Answer (score 3):

This is [a link to the answer from the author himself](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2006/06/105895.php) when this question was formulated on boost mailing list

Summarizing it, in the author opinion, implementing comparison operators (!= and <) would add more requirements on the types used to create the variant type.

I don't agree with his point of view though, since != can be implemented in the same way as ==, without necessarily hiding the possible implementations of these operators for each of the types making up the variant

Answer (score 2):

Because it doesn't need to.

Boost has an [operators library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) which defines operator!= in term of operator==

Comment: I could be wrong. But if variant uses the operators library, doesn't that mean that a != b *should* work? I think what he wants is using std::rel_ops instead: { using std::rel_ops::operator!=; getA() != getB(); }

Comment: I didn't meant to say variant is using the lib itself, but that you can do it yourself to inject operator!=

Comment: So the expectation is to include an additional header and add a using declaration in source files where != is desired?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: it is also good to diminish inter dependencies between libraries, and let the clients bind the features together at a higher level if they need it, when its easy. but let us make so that `bcp` will extract the less files as possible. the compiler configuration part of boost alone already pulls one thousand files.